# How to install Jmeter CA Certificate?

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter 3.0 there is no any option to enter Server name or Ip Address, then how i can install "JMETER CA CERTIFICATE FOR HTTPS RECORDING"?

Comment: Please mention what you have done so far.

Comment: Actually i want to record test script through mobile phone, but when we click on start button that time it will give message please install ca certificate but when we install ca certificate that time there is no any option to provide server name or server ip address.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-generating and re-installing certificate, JMeter's self-signed certificates have limited validity time. See [HTTPS recording and certificates](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) section of the JMeter User manual on HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

An alternative option to capture mobile traffic could be using [Mobile Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) service - basically a cloud proxy which simplifies HTTPS recording by providing certificates for popular mobile operating systems.

Comment: This workded for me. thanks. Also make sure to set the proxy for all protocoles.

Answer (score 2):

See this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Particularly the paragraph **Installing the certificate in Firefox**

Comment: No it’s not dead

Answer (score 1):

How to install root certificate on mac :-
If you have installed jmeter using homebrew then for the mapping of folder structure in mac and windows i.e. to find where to find the root ca certificate, please follow the below link :-

https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/using-homebrew-to-install-and-configure-jmeter-under-mac-osx/

Answer (score 1):

You need to install CA certificate to the browser If you have installed JMeter then map for folder structure in windows, to find the root ca certificate, please follow the below steps & Choose the following options:-

> 1. Tools / Options

> 2. Advanced / Certificates

> 3. View Certificates

> 4. Authorities

> 5. Import certificate from path `...\JMeter\bin\ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`

> 6. Browse to the JMeter launch directory, and click on the file ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt, press Open

> 7. Click View and check that the certificate details agree with the ones displayed by the JMeter Test Script Recorder

> 8. If OK, select "Trust this CA to identify web sites", and press OK

> 9. Close dialogues by pressing OK as necessary

Note:- These steps are only for Window OS

Comment: These steps dont work on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

FOR MACOS USERS -

1. install Jmeter with `brew install JMeter.
2. setup your thread group and test script recorder.
3. Play the test recorder as soon as you will play it will generate the certificate for you in the Jmeter bin location which is `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter/5.5/libexec/bin`
4. Open the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file it will open the keychain application, (install it in system not i-cloud).
5. you will see the certificate in system tab just double click on it and under trust section choose `allow trust`.
6. Open the required browser and setup the proxy, if you don't want to do manually use [SwithcyOmega (Brwoser Extension To Manage Proxy Easily)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif?hl=en)

That's it.